# What's the easiest way to find the equation of a straight line in polar form given two points?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Given the points $(r_1, \theta_1)$ and $(r_2, \theta_2)$, what is the easiest way to write a straight line equation between the two? I am also wondering if this parametrisation works:
$$r(t)=(1-t)r_1 + tr_2,$$ $$\theta(t) = (1-t)\theta_1+t\theta_2$$
(Desmos seems to be struggling with that and taking them as cartesian coordinates)

Comment: It is probably easier to work with the Cartesian coordinates of the points to find a line $ \ Ax + By \ = \ C \ $ containing them, then convert to $$ A·r \cos \theta \ + \ B·r \sin \theta \ \ = \ \ C \ \ $$ and factor that to obtain $ \ r \ $ as a function of $ \ \theta \ . $  (This will handle horizontal, vertical, and oblique lines properly.)

Comment: have you changed desmos settings to polar coordinates? it'll interpret as Cartesian unless you go into the top right n change it

Comment: @tai yes but it turns out desmos does not support polar equations of the form $\theta=$

Answer (score 0):

$\text{If using } r(t)=(1-t)r_1 + tr_2 \text{  parametrization},$ the standard polar form for parametrization from triangle $ OTP$

$$ r \cos (\theta - \alpha)= p $$

[image]

$$\theta(t) = \sec^{-1}\frac{r(t)}{p} + \alpha =\cos^{-1}\frac{p}{r(t)} + \alpha $$
$$\theta(t) = \sec^{-1}\frac{(1-t)r_1 + tr_2}{p} + \alpha=\cos^{-1}\frac{p}{(1-t)r_1 + tr_2} + \alpha.$$

Comment: what are $p$ and $\alpha$ here?

Comment: They are defined in the triangle OTP.